# Does caja.appspot.com cache cajoled objects

Tags: google-caja

I'm developing a site which use Google Caja to sandbox my javascript. I'm using the server at caja.appspot.com to cajole my html,js and css. However it does seem to cache the cajoled object for some time which is quite anoying when developing. For me it seems to take about five minutes before my updated content get cajoled. Does anyone now if this is the case and if it can be turned off?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on the caja discussion group at google and got an answer there. caja.appspot.com do cache url:s. The max-age however is now changed to 10s which makes developing much more pleasant. Another workaround is to append a unique string to the URL that you cajoling like ?id=345.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-caja-discuss/fZxJDQ5HL58